# Selectively start elixir applications in an umbrella

Tags: elixir

How to control which applications in an umbrella project start, for my specific use case:

1. Only start certain applications if they are not already running in the cluster (e.g. Singleton application)
2. Only start certain applications based on the name of the node (e.g. some applications may use remote systems that have IP address restrictions)
3. Do not start any apps automatically when opening a console (e.g. iex -S mix)

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about 1 and 2, but `iex -S mix run --no-start` should work for the console case.

Answer (score 6):

You can handle #1 by using OTPs *distributed applications* capability. You need to configure the `kernel` application like so:

```
config :kernel, :distributed, [
  {:app1, 5_000, [:"node1@<x.x.x.x>", {:"node2@<x.x.x.y>", :"node3@<x.x.x.z>"}]},
  {:app2, [:"node2@<x.x.x.y>", {:"node1@<x.x.x.x>", :"node3@<x.x.x.z>"}]},
  ...
]

config :kernel,
  sync_nodes_mandatory: [:"node1@<x.x.x.x>", :"node2@<x.x.x.y>", ...],
  sync_nodes_timeout: 5_000
```

The above will ensure that `app1` is started on `node1`, and if `node1` goes down or is unavailable, it will try one of the backup nodes, `node2` or `node3` (the order is undefined). It will also require that this occurs within 5 seconds. Similarly, `app2` will be started on `node2`, or failing that, one of the backups, but it has no timeout for starting.

The other two kernel settings will require that before any applications are started, all of the nodes in the list are connected, and that must happen within 5 seconds or the boot process will fail.

All of these settings can be tweaked as necessary depending on what is required in your cluster. It's not quite the same as automatically determining a node to assign an application to, but it will ensure it is only running on *one* of the nodes.

You can read more about this in the Erlang manual, in the [Distributed Applications](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/distributed_applications.html) document.

The above also somewhat fulfills your request for #2, but it's less about starting based on the name of the node, and more that you configure the nodes the application is allowed to run on, and it will do so. You could manage this yourself, by using `included_applications`, and starting them conditionally based on the current node name, or some other criteria, but this will require that you start those included applications as part of the supervisor tree of the including application. Depending on how your umbrella is set up, that may mean that you need to create a "shell" app, which is primarily responsible for coordinating the start up and configuration of included applications. You can read more about those [here](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/included_applications.html)

Comment: thanks @bitwalker, based on your answer I was able to google how to get this done in an Elixir project and came across this blog post which elaborates on your answer: https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/01/28/running-elixir-and-phoenix-projects-on-a-cluster-of-nodes